# Why the second if condition is evaluated, even though the condition is not even satisfied?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int a=10;
if (a == a--)
    printf("true1\t\n");
a=10;
if(a == --a)
{
    printf("true2");
}
return 0;}
```

as in the second if condition a=10 and --a is 9 i.e 10 != 9 so how come the second condition is evaluated ?

Comment: Google for **Undefined Behaviour**; I'm sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 7):

The value of `--a` is the previous value of `a` minus `1`.

Furthermore that expression has the side-effect of changing the value of `a`.

The left part of the comparison is the value of `a` ... but is it the value of `a` before or after the side-effect has been applied?

The C Standard does not force the sequence of checking the value and applying the side-effect; and says that reading the value of a variable and changing its value without an intervening sequence point is **Undefined Behaviour**.

Basically there is a sequence point at every `;` in the program (it's not as straightforward); your expression (`a == --a`) does not have sequence points.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the next rule is also valid in C as in Java :
The --x has a higher priority than x--

```
a=10;
printf(a--) // should be showing 10;
a=10;
printf(--a) //should be showing 9
```

Comment: Though it is true (I didn't downvote), a) not really related to question, b) it's not valid C.